# Cant get view of the form in thymeleaf after put to it list of object

Tags: spring, thymeleaf

I have a big problem to solve and I don`t see the sollution of this, because IntelliJ not given me any log. Here is the point:
When I try to open the page with form where I put data od employee and address, address form is invisible. 
My code:

```
View:
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>Dodaj nową firmę</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/webjars/bootstrap/4.4.1-1/css/bootstrap.min.css}" />

    <script th:src="@{/webjars/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js}"></script>
    <script th:src="@{/webjars/bootstrap/4.4.1-1/js/bootstrap.min.js}"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div style = "text-align: center;">
        <h1>Dodaj nowego pracownika do bazy danych</h1>
    </div>
    <form class="form-horizontal"  th:object="${employee}" th:action="@{/employees}"  th:method="post">
        <div class="container" style="margin-top:10mm;">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm">
                    <div style = "text-align: center;">
                        <h5>Dane osobowe</h5>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{name}"/>
                        <label class="control-label">Imię</label>
                        <div class="text-danger"><p th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('name')}" th:errors="*{name}"/></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{surname}"/>
                        <label class="control-label">Nazwisko</label>
                        <div class="text-danger"><p th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('surname')}" th:errors="*{surname}"/></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{position}"/>
                        <label class="control-label">Stanowisko</label>
                        <div class="text-danger"><p th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('position')}" th:errors="*{position}"/></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="number" class="form-control" th:field="*{age}"/>
                        <label class="control-label">Wiek</label>
                        <div class="text-danger"><p th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('age')}" th:errors="*{age}"/></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{nationality}"/>
                        <label class="control-label">Obywatelstwo</label>
                        <div class="text-danger"><p th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('nationality')}" th:errors="*{nationality}"/></div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm">
                    <div th:object="${listAddress}">
                        <div style = "text-align: center;">
                            <h5>Dane adresowe</h5>
                        </div>
                        <div style = "text-align: center;">
                            <h6>Adres stały</h6>
                        </div>

                        <div th:each="row, stat : ${listAddress.addresses}">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{addresses[__${stat.index}__].type}"/>
                                <label class="control-label">Typ adresu</label>
<!--                                <div class="text-danger"><p th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('type')}" th:errors="*{type}"/></div>-->
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{addresses[__${stat.index}__].street}"/>
                                <label class="control-label">Ulica</label>
<!--                                <div class="text-danger"><p th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('street')}" th:errors="*{street}"/></div>-->
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="number" class="form-control" th:field="*{addresses[__${stat.index}__].streetNr}"/>
                                <label class="control-label">Numer domu</label>
<!--                                <div class="text-danger"><p th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('streetNr')}" th:errors="*{streetNr}"/></div>-->
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{addresses[__${stat.index}__].flatNr}"/>
                                <label class="control-label">Numer mieszkania</label>
<!--                                <div class="text-danger"><p th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('flatNr')}" th:errors="*{flatNr}"/></div>-->
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{addresses[__${stat.index}__].postalCode}"/>
                                <label class="control-label">Kod pocztowy</label>
<!--                                <div class="text-danger"><p th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('postalCode')}" th:errors="*{postalCode}"/></div>-->
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{addresses[__${stat.index}__].city}"/>
                                <label class="control-label">Miasto</label>
<!--                                <div class="text-danger"><p th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('city')}" th:errors="*{city}"/></div>-->
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{addresses[__${stat.index}__].country}"/>
                                <label class="control-label">Kraj</label>
<!--                                <div class="text-danger"><p th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('country')}" th:errors="*{country}"/></div>-->
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                   <div style = "text-align: right;">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg active center-block">ZAPISZ</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping("/new")
    public String addNewEmployee(Model model) {
        AddressesList listOfAddress = new AddressesList();
        ArrayList<Address> addressesArray = new ArrayList<>();
        listOfAddress.setAddresses(addressesArray);
        model.addAttribute("employee", new Employee()).addAttribute("listAddress", listOfAddress);

        return "new_employee_form";
    }
```

AddressList class

```
public class AddressesList {

    private List<Address> addresses;

    public AddressesList() {
    }

    public AddressesList(List<Address> addresses) {
        this.addresses = addresses;
    }

    public List<Address> getAddresses() {
        return addresses;
    }

    public void setAddresses(List<Address> addresses) {
        this.addresses = addresses;
    }
}
```

Address class

```
public class Address {

    public Long idAddress;
    public Long idEmployee;
    public String type;
    public String street;
    public String streetNr;
    public Integer flatNr;
    public String postalCode;
    public String city;
    public String country;

    public Address() {
    }

    private Address(Long idEmployee, String type, String street, Integer flatNr, String streetNr, String postalCode, String city, String country) {
        this.idEmployee = idEmployee;
        this.type = type;
        this.street = street;
        this.streetNr = streetNr;
        this.flatNr = flatNr;
        this.postalCode = postalCode;
        this.city = city;
        this.country = country;
    }

    public static class AddressBuilder{
        private Long idAddress;
        private Long idEmployee;
        private String type;
        private String street;
        private String streetNumber;
        private Integer flatNr;
        private String postalCode;
        private String city;
        private String country;

        public AddressBuilder setIdEmployee(Long idEmployee) {
            this.idEmployee = idEmployee;
            return this;
        }

        public AddressBuilder setType(String type) {
            this.type = type;
            return this;
        }

        public AddressBuilder setStreet(String street) {
            this.street = street;
            return this;
        }

        public AddressBuilder setFlatNr(Integer flatNr) {
            this.flatNr = flatNr;
            return this;
        }

        public AddressBuilder setStreetNumber(String streetNumber) {
            this.streetNumber = streetNumber;
            return this;
        }

        public AddressBuilder setPostalCode(String postalCode) {
            this.postalCode = postalCode;
            return this;
        }

        public AddressBuilder setCity(String city) {
            this.city = city;
            return this;
        }

        public AddressBuilder setCountry(String country) {
            this.country = country;
            return this;
        }

        public Address build(){
            return new Address(idEmployee, type, street, flatNr, streetNumber, postalCode, city, country);
        }
    }

    public void setIdAddress(Long idAddress) {
        this.idAddress = idAddress;
    }

    public void setIdEmployee(Long idEmployee) {
        this.idEmployee = idEmployee;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public void setStreet(String street) {
        this.street = street;
    }

    public void setFlatNr(Integer flatNr) {
        this.flatNr = flatNr;
    }

    public void setStreetNr(String streetNr) {
        this.streetNr = streetNr;
    }

    public void setPostalCode(String postalCode) {
        this.postalCode = postalCode;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }

    public Long getIdAddress() {
        return idAddress;
    }

    public Long getIdEmployee() {
        return idEmployee;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public String getStreet() {
        return street;
    }

    public Integer getFlatNr() {
        return flatNr;
    }

    public String getStreetNr() {
        return streetNr;
    }

    public String getPostalCode() {
        return postalCode;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Address{" +
                "idAddress=" + idAddress +
                ", idEmployee=" + idEmployee +
                ", type='" + type + '\'' +
                ", street='" + street + '\'' +
                ", flattNr=" + flatNr +
                ", streetNumber='" + streetNr + '\'' +
                ", postalCode='" + postalCode + '\'' +
                ", city='" + city + '\'' +
                ", country='" + country + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

I get the page like this with no errors
[image]

with no address form on the right side od page.
Please help to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding an empty list of addresses to your backing object:

```
ArrayList<Address> addressesArray = new ArrayList<>();
listOfAddress.setAddresses(addressesArray);
```

If you want the form to show up, you need to add at least one address so it has something to loop over.

```
ArrayList<Address> addressesArray = new ArrayList<>();
addressesArray.add(new Address());
listOfAddress.setAddresses(addressesArray);
```

Comment: Hmm but I can add address to ArrayList over when the form will be visible. Is therer other way to show form of address? For example employee is empty too and the form of it is visible.

Comment: Why are you okay with adding an empty employee `model.addAttribute("employee", new Employee())` but not an empty `Address`?  If you want the form to be visible, then you have to have something to bind the fields too.  You are looping over an empty array here: `<div th:each="row, stat : ${listAddress.addresses}">`.

Answer (score 0):

I think I do this wrong.
When I add index to ArrayList form showed up.

```
    @RequestMapping("/new")
public String addNewEmployee(Model model) {
    AddressesList listOfAddress = new AddressesList();
    ArrayList<Address> addressesArray = new ArrayList<Address>(2);
    addressesArray.add(0, new Address());
    addressesArray.add(1, new Address());
    listOfAddress.setAddresses(addressesArray);
    model.addAttribute("employee", new Employee()).addAttribute("listAddress", listOfAddress);

    return "new_employee_form";
}
```

I want to enter a permanent and correspondence address in the form, accept the form (POST) and save it to class objects. How to do it?